# Обновление интерпертатора Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Всем здравствуйте. Использую Spyder v.5 с версией Python 3.7.8. Хочу обновиться до 3.10. Проблема состоит в том, что если я устанавливаю python 3.10 через pip в командной строке и подключаю его как интерпретатор Spyder, мне пишут, что отсутствует ядро Spyder.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следуя рекомендациям, устанавливаю ядро через pip - но ничего не меняется. Перезапуск IDE не приводит к положительному результату. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ну так а spyder если обновить?

Comment: Последняя версия стоит.